# How to run more than one local node (express) app on single port on local machine?

Tags: node.js, express, localhost

I tried app.use : API's are not working getting 404

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app
  .use('/app', require('../app1/app.js').app)
  .use('/app1', require('../app2/app.js').app)
  .listen(5005);
```